# Sharepoint Online Rest Query with $expand generating 400 bad request

Tags: rest, sharepoint

I have 2 sharepoint lists setup to represent different groups(circles) and the users that are apart of those groups(circles).

> **List**: Circles **Columns**: Circle(single line of text)
>
> **List**: UserCircles **Columns**: UserName(person lookup), UserCirlce(lookup to Circle list)

In the setup, all of the columns are their own columns (I have not renamed the title column to Circle or anything like that). I have not changed the display names of the lists.

When I try to run an REST GET against the UserCircles list and retrieve the projected values from the Circles list as below:

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('UserCircles')/items?$select=Circles/Circle&$expand=Circles
```

I get a HTTP 400 Error and the message:
***The field or property 'Circles' does not exist***

I can successfully run a query against the UserName field (I assume that's the referenced field), by running the below query:

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('UserCircles')/items?$select=Author/Title&$expand=Author
```

I am not sure why the query cannot find the list specified.  I have verified all of the list names.  Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in your example, since the name of lookup field is `UserCirlce`, the query should be like this:

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('UserCircles')/items?$select=UserCirlce/Circle&$expand=UserCirlce
```

> Note: the name of lookup field have to be specified in `$expand` query
>   option

The list of examples for syntax's of `$expand` query option:

- `/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('<listtitle>')/items?$select=<lookupfieldname>/<projectedfieldname>&$expand=<lookupfieldname>`
- `/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('<listtitle>')/items?$select=<lookupfieldname>/<projectedfieldname1>,<lookupfieldname>/<projectedfieldname2>&$expand=<lookupfieldname>`

Comment: That was it!  Thank you @vadim for the two examples you listed.  The query that finally worked was

/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('UserCircles')/items?$select=CircleName/Circle&$expand=CircleName

My understanding is that the syntax goes: $select=<currentListField1>/<relatedListField1>&expand=<currentListField1>